# Is there any way to Run codes between multiple Nodes on HPC

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

I am trying to run let's say 10 different codes each saved in it's respective directory named as 1,2,3,..,10.

```
#PBS -l nodes=10:cores=1
```

This means I had 1 thread each on 10 different CPU's. Now I had to submit a job so that each directory get's 1 thread of 1 CPU only, and similarly other directories 2,3..,10. 
Codes are for molecular dynamics and runs for several hours, and they are independent as well. I tried by Gnu Parallel but I failed to employ each 10 CPU's. May be Gnu Parallel is made to distribute jobs in between 1 CPU cores. I know MPI can, but I don't know exactly how. May anyone please suggest.

Comment: You may wish to familiariase yourself with the concept of **array jobs**.

Comment: Yes, but if I am correct, then let's say I submit 1 job with 10 array jobs then the PBS will runs 10 individuals jobs merged into 1 main submitted job. But I have a limit I can only run 20 jobs at a time in my university. That's the whole point of learning Nodes distribution of jobs because I want ensemble average and needs to run 1000s of jobs.

Comment: `pbsdsh` can help you here, see https://linux.die.net/man/1/pbsdsh

This will likely end in a suboptimal solution in which all the nodes have to wait for the slowest one. So instead of trying to game the system, you'd rather have a chat with your sysadmin, and explain a job array of 200 single node jobs is more efficient than running 20 jobs running on 10 nodes each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have access to a PBS cluster, but Example 2 from
https://www.nas.nasa.gov/hecc/support/kb/using-gnu-parallel-to-package-multiple-jobs-in-a-single-pbs-job_303.html might be what you are looking for:

```
#PBS -lselect=6:ncpus=4:model=san
#PBS -lwalltime=4:00:00

cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR

seq 64 | parallel -j 4 -u --sshloginfile $PBS_NODEFILE \
 "cd $PWD; ./myscript.csh {}"
```

Adapted to your situation (untested):

```
#PBS -l place=scatter
#PBS -l nodes=10:cores=1

cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR

seq 10 | parallel -j 1 --sshloginfile $PBS_NODEFILE --wd $PBS_O_WORKDIR ./myscript {}
```

You need `place=scatter` because otherwise the same host may be listed twice in `$PBS_NODEFILE`, and GNU Parallel ignores duplicates.

Comment: I am very thankful as it solved my problem. I modified myscript.csh little bit, (deleted last line, added cd $1;./a where a is a precompiled file saved in respective directories.)

Comment: I am still having some strange issues to which I will update once I get any clear reason. Eg. out 10, first 5 are running in parallel, and rest 5 starts only after first 5 folders finishes. I can not ask the issue as I don't understand it clearly why

Comment: @yasir What is the content of `cat $PBS_NODEFILE`?

Comment: I am trying with 4 nodes & 1 core each and results with cat $PBS_NODEFILE are,
chas005.hpc.iitd.ac.in
chas005.hpc.iitd.ac.in
chas005.hpc.iitd.ac.in
chas005.hpc.iitd.ac.in

Comment: The problem is, that PBS apparently repeats the same server. GNU Parallel only looks at unique server names, so if the same server is mentioned 4 times, it really only counts as one. If you want 4 processes running on that you can do: -j100% -S4/chas005.hpc.iitd.ac.in

Comment: I got it now the reason why sometimes 2 were running simultaneously and 1 only in another time, is because of the Node name. This solves my problem. In a general case can i ask if suppose I have 3 nodes, 2 cores each and let's say PBS assigned Nodes N1,N2,N3 but assume N1 and N2 are same. In that case I tried, 'seq 6 | parallel -j100% --wd . -S 2/"$N1" -S 2/"$N2" -S 2/"$N3" ./b1.c {}' Now I see 4 are running and 2 are waiting because of the reason you mentioned. 
Is it further possible to force GNU parallel to differentiate N1 & N2, which unfortunately has the same name?

Comment: I added following line on PBS,'#PBS -l place=scatter', now It gives me different nodes. Hence the first script you mentioned works smoothly. Thanks.